# Ice geometrical shapes

Tags: water, solid-state-chemistry

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice

https://www.google.com/search?q=ice&prmd=inmv&sxsrf=ALeKk028fJvrUcWLWu8EV-KsRGuiw0iWWw:1596098668929&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqjcDxyvTqAhWZaCsKHY36BIYQ_AUoAXoECBMQAQ

Can Ice formation creation possible for all geometrical shapes viz Rectangle, Square, Circular, Cylinder, Kite, Cone, Rhombus, Sphere, Cube etc?

If yes, What is the process?
If no, Why?

Comment: Do you mean with the lattice structure or just the shape of the ice block? If it is just shape then it only depends on the mold you use

Comment: Pour water into any shape, and it will freeze in that shape. There is no chemistry behind it.

Comment: With the Lattice structure. Can we create a Cone or Cylinder structure of Ice?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sxsrf=ALeKk00nBSln87IXevZplyFbiNzikRyRWg%3A1596100051626&source=hp&ei=040iX-qhJI-T4-EPmJuMwAY&q=lattice+structure+of+ice&oq=Lattice+structure+of+ice&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQARgAMgIIADIGCAAQBRAeOgcIIxDqAhAnOgQIIxAnOggIABCxAxCDAToFCAAQsQM6BAgAEAM6BAgAEBhQqgxYoGZgrXBoAXAAeACAAasFiAHJJpIBDDAuMTcuMS4xLjEuMpgBAKABAbABBQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-img  https://www.stlfinder.com/3dmodels/lattice-structure-of-ice/

Comment: The answer of this question does not depend on the scientist's will. It depends on the nature. The crystalline form cannot be obtained by calculation. It is an experimental observation. Nobody knows why ice is cubic or orthorhombic in a given domain of temperature and pressure. Nobody can predict the limit of these domains. It cannot be predicted.

Comment: Lattice structure is ***not*** a relevant or useful concept when making ice cubes. Stop thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wish to refer to the fact that different forms of ice called ice phases of water are available. Like if under great pressure, in some gas giants like neptune, ice VII may form which has a cubical structure.

For more information on the different ice phases, [Water Structure and Science](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/ice_phases.html) would be a good read.